# AnnotationReader class not found

Tags: jaxb, dependencies, osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I have a problem with dependencies in ServiceMix.

I try to start a bundle. 
This bundle has several imports:

```
Import-Package =
        org.apache.camel;version="[2.16,3)",
        org.apache.camel.builder;version="[2.16,3)",
        org.apache.camel.osgi;version="[2.16,3)",
        org.springframework.cglib.core,
        org.springframework.cglib.proxy,
        org.springframework.beans.factory,
        org.springframework.cglib.reflect,
        org.apache.camel.spring;version="[2.16,3)",
        com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation;resolution:=optional;version="[2.2.0,3.0.0)"
```

Those requirements are resolved as follow:

```
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel)(version>=2.16.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.apache.camel 2.16.5 from org.apache.camel.camel-core [46]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.builder)(version>=2.16.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.apache.camel.builder 2.16.5 from org.apache.camel.camel-core [46]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.osgi)(version>=2.16.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.apache.camel.osgi 2.16.5 from org.apache.camel.camel-spring [50]
osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.cglib.core) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.springframework.cglib.core 3.2.18.RELEASE from org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core [155]
osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.cglib.proxy) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.springframework.cglib.proxy 3.2.18.RELEASE from org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core [155]
osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.beans.factory) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.springframework.beans.factory 3.2.18.RELEASE from org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans [152]
osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.cglib.reflect) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.springframework.cglib.reflect 3.2.18.RELEASE from org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core [155]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.spring)(version>=2.16.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.apache.camel.spring 2.16.5 from org.apache.camel.camel-spring [50]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation)(version>=2.2.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation 2.2.11 from org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl [562]
osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5)) resolved by:
   osgi.ee; JavaSE [1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0] from org.apache.felix.framework [0]
service; [org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin] provided by:
   org.apache.felix.framework [0]
service; [org.xml.sax.EntityResolver] provided by:
   org.springframework.osgi.extender [219]
service; [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerResolver] provided by:
   org.springframework.osgi.extender [219]
```

But when I start my bundle I have the following error:

```
2018-01-10 17:45:19,950 | ERROR | ExtenderThread-1 | ContextLoaderListener            | 219 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.1 | Application context refresh failed (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=myBundle, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml))
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [bundle://638.0:0/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)[152:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.18.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)[152:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.18.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)[152:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.18.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)[152:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.18.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)[152:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.18.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)[152:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.18.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:164)[218:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:136)[218:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)[153:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.18.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)[153:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.18.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$800(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)[218:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$3.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:269)[218:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[218:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.startRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:247)[218:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.stageOne(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:214)[219:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.refresh(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:169)[219:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:175)[218:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.activator.ContextLoaderListener$2.run(ContextLoaderListener.java:716)[219:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)[:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2310)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2094)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1518)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1958)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)[:1.8.0_151]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:137)[:2.8.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:310)[:2.8.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446)[:2.8.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:409)[:2.8.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.newJAXBContext(DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.java:31)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.getJaxbContext(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:200)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:361)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:59)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1432)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1422)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:101)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.doImplicitBootDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1764)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.2.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchDynamicImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1693)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.2.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1528)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.2.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.2.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1958)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.2.jar:]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.8.0_151]
        ... 48 more
```

... as if the package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation wasn't found by my bundle although it is resolved...

When I list all the classes provided by the bundle "org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl [562]":

```
karaf@root>bundle:classes 562 | grep AnnotationReader
com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AbstractInlineAnnotationReaderImpl.class
com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader.class
com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/RuntimeAnnotationReader.class
com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.class
```

... I find the AnnotationReader class.

Does someone know why my bundle does not find this class?

Thanks a lot!

Hejk

Answer (score 0):

The problem would appear to be the bundle's import for the following:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation;resolution:=optional;version="[2.2.0,3.0.0)"
```

It's not a good idea to import implementation packages from the JVM, and in this case the import is marked optional when it really shouldn't be.

Normally the OSGi framework can boot delegate internal JVM types, but in this case the bundle has explicitly imported the package, meaning that it has to come from a package wiring within the OSGi framework. As the import is optional the framework is allowed not to create this wire, and if it doesn't then the package simply does not exist as far as the importing bundle is concerned. It is the importers job to handle optionality properly, which is clearly not happening in this case.

To fix this it is probably sufficient to remove the offending import and to rely on using the portable JAXB API. Do you have any idea why the import might be there in the first place? It is unusual for optional imports to exist except when your build tool has been explicitly configured to add them.

Comment: I have removed the import. It doesn't change anything, I still have the same error when I start my bundle: do you have an idea why? What do you mean by " to rely on using the portable JAXB API" ? Thanks!

Comment: The stack trace indicates that the code is using JAXBContext.newInstance(), which is portable API (i.e. a standard implemented by several different libraries). This is better than coupling to a specific implementation, for example com.sun.xml.bind.

Comment: OK, I get it. Now my bundle doesn't rely on a specific implementation because I removed the import, right? The code that uses JAXBContext is probably Apache Camel, so not in my scope. But I have the same stacktrace as before. I don't really know what to do now. I'm a bit stuck with those dependencies for a while...